# Can my AWS CloudFormation stack's Spot Fleet resource be a "request" instead of "maintain"-ed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to have an `AWS::EC2::SpotFleet` resource in my stack that's set to be a one-time `request` **instead of** a `maintain`-ed fleet (see [the EC2 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/spot-fleet-requests.html) for the difference)?

The [EC2 API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_SpotFleetRequestConfigData.html) offers a `Type` property, but [the CloudFormation template reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata.html) doesn't offer it, failing validation and rolling back during stack creation.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Same issue with error ‘Encountered unsupported property Type’ - did you find an alternative way to specify it?

Comment: @user1811107 No, I'm working around the lack of this facility by playing terrible games with non-destructive resizing of my fleets. For example: create a fleet of 10 instances, poll on it until the spot requests are fulfilled, then resize the fleet down to 1 instance (without terminating instances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Yes, as of **Aug 18 2017**, it is now possible to specify the [`SpotFleetRequestConfigData.Type`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata.html#cfn-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata-type) parameter (either `request` or `maintain`) in the [`AWS::EC2::SpotFleet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-spotfleet.html) CloudFormation resource implementation.

---

(original answer from Dec 31 2016 below)

No, it's currently not possible to specify the [`SpotFleetRequestConfig.Type`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_SpotFleetRequestConfigData.html) request parameter in the [`RequestSpotFleet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RequestSpotFleet.html) API call through the [`SpotFleetRequestConfigData`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata.html) parameter in the [`AWS::EC2::SpotFleet`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-spotfleet.html) CloudFormation resource implementation.

The `AWS::EC2::SpotFleet` CloudFormation resource was originally added [October 1 2015](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html), and the Spot Fleet `Type` parameter was added to the API sometime around [June 2 2016](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/06a832f37909cd676e7aab7b8783dcff99d96d1f). Presumably, the work necessary to update the resource implementation to match the new EC2 API has not been prioritized since then. (Many of the official CloudFormation resources lag behind their AWS API counterparts in this manner, unfortunately).

As a workaround, you could implement your own Lambda-backed [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that uses the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) to call [`requestSpotFleet`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#requestSpotFleet-property) directly. The AWS SDKs tend to track additions/evolutions to the AWS APIs *much* more quickly than the corresponding CloudFormation resources.